# Powershell Script: "Get-ADGroupMember xxx | select name" -> write-host in a list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing my first script in Powershell. I am using the command "Get-ADGroupMember xxx | select name".

When I type it in Powershell directly the ouput is a list:

```
name
----
User1
User2
User3
```

But when I use it in my script:

```
$Texto = Get-ADGroupMember xxx | select name
write-host = $Texto
```

The output is this:

```
$Texto = Get-ADGroupMember xxx | select name
write-host = $Texto
= @{name=User1} @{name=User2} @{name=User3}
```

how can I write this in my script so I can see it in a List?

Comment: Look up `-ExpandProperty` (so many questions about this) and `Write-Host` is a cmdlet, not a variable you can assign a value to with `=`

Answer (score 0):

Your `$Texto` is not a text, but rather an array of objects, which you can use for further processing. If you just wish to have the same output, just skip `Write-Host` and just refer to your variable directly, like so:

```
$Texto = Get-ADGroupMember xxx | select name
$Texto
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
do you kknow how I can write this array into a Rich Text Box?